# javascript table fill in different ways

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have function. It works and fill table good.

```
function fillTable(data){
  t.innerHTML="";

  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    t.innerHTML+='<tr class="rowRes"><td class="id">'+data[i]["id"]+'</td><td class="firstName">'+data[i]["firstName"]+'</td><td class="lastName">'+data[i]["lastName"]+'</td><td class="email">'+data[i]["email"]+'</td><td class="phone">'+data[i]["phone"]+'</td></tr>';
  }
  getClickTable ();
}
```

But when i'm trying to write it in short form. It fills all data in one column.

```
function fillTable(data){
  t.innerHTML="";

  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    t.innerHTML+='<tr class="rowRes">'
    var mass=["id", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "phone"];
      for (let j=0; j<mass.length; j++){
        t.innerHTML+='<td class='+mass[j]+'>'+data[i][mass[j]]+ '</td>';
  }

    t.innerHTML+='</tr>';
  }
  getClickTable ();
}
```

What's wrong ? Why it make each cell in different row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the problem as you are directly setting the HTML using `.innerHTML` property thus modern browsers are trying to fix the issue due to partial HTML.

Use a variable to generate HTML and set it later.

```
function fillTable(data) {
    var str = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        str += '<tr class="rowRes">'
        var mass = ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "phone"];
        for (let j = 0; j < mass.length; j++) {
            str += '<td class=' + mass[j] + '>' + data[i][mass[j]] + '</td>';
        }
        str += '</tr>';
    }
    t.innerHTML = str;
    getClickTable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why it doesn't work without it ? )))

Comment: @Redair, when you add an element to DOM reflow/repaint happen and the browser tries to fix the partial HTML, thus you are getting broken result

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with this.

[mass[j]] this field returns undefined value.

Comment: Really? I'm playing around with it a little out of curiosity but did not experience this. Plz see https://jsfiddle.net/h9p3z3uc/